# Adding arbitrary data to OData metadata in WebAPI?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a simple WebAPI2 service that uses OData (`System.Web.Http.OData`, 5.1.0.0).  Users can hit `/odata/$metadata` to get the available entities and properties.  I'm looking for a way to extend this metadata with additional information, such as adding a "display name" value to a property.

I found information about "annotations" that sounds like it is what I want, but I cannot find anything explanining how to use this in my scenario or if it is even possible.  I was trying to do something like the following:

```
model.SetAnnotationValue(((IEdmEntityType)m.FindType("My.Thing")).FindProperty("SomeProperty"),
       namespaceName:"MyNamespace",
       localName: "SomeLocalName",
       value: "THINGS");
```

The type/property names are correct and the call succeeds, but the OData EDMX document does not contain this annotation.  Is there some way to expose these annotations or otherwise do what I want?

**Update**:
Still at it.  I've been looking at `ODataMediaTypeFormatters` as a possible way to handle this.  There is an [ASP.NET sample project](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#Samples/WebApi/CustomODataFormatter/CustomODataFormatter/ReadMe.txt) that shows how to add instance annotations to entities.  Close, but not exactly what I want, so now I'm trying to find a way to extend whatever generates the metadata document in a similar way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this.  The code below adds a custom namespace prefix "myns" and then adds an annotation on a model property:

```
const string namespaceName = "http://my.org/schema";
var type = "My.Domain.Person";
const string localName = "MyCustomAttribute";

// this registers a "myns" namespace on the model
model.SetNamespacePrefixMappings(new [] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("myns", namespaceName), });

// set a simple string as the value of the "MyCustomAttribute" annotation on the "RevisionDate" property
var stringType = EdmCoreModel.Instance.GetString(true);
var value = new EdmStringConstant(stringType, "BUTTONS!!!");
m.SetAnnotationValue(((IEdmEntityType) m.FindType(type)).FindProperty("RevisionDate"),
                        namespaceName, localName, value);
```

Requesting the OData metadata document should give you something like this:

```
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0">
    <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="3.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0">
        <Schema Namespace="My.Domain">
            <EntityType Name="Person">
                <Key><PropertyRef Name="PersonId"/></Key>
                <Property Name="RevisionDate" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" myns:MyCustomAttribute="BUTTONS!!!"/>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Comment: @raddium i have used this implementation and it works perfectly, I am facing an issue where i want to add a custom attribute on  <EntityType Name="Person">. Is this possible? tried by removing the .FindProperty("RevisionDate").

Answer (score -1):

You can set a custom property to any IEdmEntityType, thus also for . Simply modify kenchilada's code as follows:

```
m.SetAnnotationValue(m.FindType(type), namespaceName, localName, value);
```